# Safari changing header colour on monile devices

Tags: css, safari, header

This is proving extremely hard to try and debug, but the number at the top of the page on ipad and iphones running safari, it initially loads in white and then changes to a dark grey.

What the hell is causing this?! It works in everything else!

www.colourfence.co.uk

Any help would be more than welcome as I've been tasked with fixing someone elses work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have link colour set to dark grey `color: #333333;`. And mobile safari automatically detects phone numbers and wraps them in `<a>` tags.

You have two options as described in [this article](https://medium.com/@stephenkeable/iphone-safari-changing-colour-of-phone-numbers-b79e5139cc06):

Either prevent automatic detection with meta tag:

```
<meta name=”format-detection” content=”telephone=no”>
```

Or force original styling with css rule:

```
a[href^=tel] {
  text-decoration:inherit;
  color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: You absolute champion!!! It was indeed picking it up as a link on safari devices!!!

I set a seperate tage in the css to overide the link colour in the relevant section and it's nailed it.

Thank you so much, I've been pulling my hair out over that! :D